# Better way of looking for present elements and toggling their visibility

Tags: jquery, toggle, visibility

I'm working on some script that runs on a series of pages. I'm looking to write a global function that looks to see if a particular element is present on the page, and to toggle its visibility. I'm wondering if there's a neater way of doing this. I think this method will toggle the elements regardless of whether they're in the page or not, but preseumably this isn't very efficient?

```
$('.flashcards, .graphic, .laddersteps, .mcq').each(function() { //more in actual list

    $(this).toggle();
})
```

Comment: why can't add a common class to all the elements that needs to be toggled

Comment: `$('.flashcards, .graphic, .laddersteps, .mcq').toggle()` will do, there is no need to use `.each()`

Comment: Arun, why do you put your answers in comments? That breaks the whole functionality of SO.

Comment: So some elements are hidden and other are visible? Or all have same visibility state and you want to hide or show them?

Comment: All have same visibility state. Thought about adding common class, but we're talking dozens of pages - would take a while to locate all elements and add common class to each.

Comment: So then, why not just use a CSS rule, you can't find better!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `each()`, jQuery already does that for you. You could just write

```
$('.flashcards, .graphic, .laddersteps, .mcq').toggle();
```

See the [API docs](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) for more info on multiple selectors.

Comment: +1 because each loop is useless here but this won't be really more efficient